# how can I put validation_errors() at the right side of textfield?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I have followed the learning tutorials in CodeIgniter and Im currently creating a program using the same procedure on my reference(link posted below) where there is a log-in form. I have no problem with the functions, I just want to put the validation_errors() at the right side of the textfield where if the username is empty or incorrect, the error message will display on the right side of the textfield. Is there a way to do this? or should I use javascript instead of using this validation_errors()? Hope someone will help me. Thanks!

Here's the code in VIEW:

```
<h3>Log-In with CodeIgniter</h3>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
<br/>
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" size="20" id="password" name="password"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log-In"/>
</form>
```

Here's the code in CONTROLLER:

```
    function index() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
    else {
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }
}

function check_database($password) {
    $username=$this->input->post('username');
    $result=$this->user->login($username, $password);
    if($result) {
        $sess_array=array();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $sess_array=array('id'=>$row->id, 'username'=>$row->username);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array); 
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**Reference: http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you provide a demo ?

Comment: its the same here on my reference: http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html

Comment: try to use tables , it may be easier for errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h3>Log-In with CodeIgniter</h3>



<?php if (form_error('password')=="Invalid username or password")
 {
    echo form_error('password');
 }
?>

<?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/><?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
<br/>
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" size="20" id="password" name="password"/><?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log-In"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I've tried to make it like this..   <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username" <?php echo form_error('username'); ?></input>  but the thing is that when username and password is incorrect, the error shows at the right side of the password field where it should be on the upper side before username field.

Comment: May i know how are you displaying the error for wrong username or password

Comment: Yes, there I edited my post on Controller Code. There I have function check_database($password) to check if the password in database is correct else it will display invalid error. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you got it.Right?

Comment: It shows the same thing. I tried to put <br/> on -invalid username or password- and it works. Your code looks good for showing errors individually. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
```

This will display all the errors of FORM at one time - they come in form of bulk errors (not splitted)

```
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
```

This is the right way of displaying the individual errors , where CodeIgniter provides you the way of displaying the error individually

[showing individual errors in codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

and search for **Showing Errors Individually**

You can display them in span tag at side of input fields - to get the kind of O/P which you want

Comment: Alright. The error shows individually to the textfield, but I really want it to display on the right side of each textfield where then the -invalid username or password- will show on the upper side before the username field.

Comment: you can alter your markup like this
<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" /><span style="color:red"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></span>

Comment: It shows the same thing and its alright. My another concern is that the -invalid username or password- error message displays on the right side of password field even if its error message called individually. I think its in my controller code where $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database'); as where I put the check_database, thanks! :)

Comment: if you got your answer plzz accept the answer, it will help in improving my profile :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did..

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', '<br/><br/>Invalid username or password');
```

I added `<br/>` to Invalid username or password so that it will not place to password field.